# Api.ai API for php (with REST API by POSTing)

Tags: php, api, rest, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es

llo,
I'm trying to integrate my webapp with  RESTful api in php. This requires me to POST data to https://api.api.ai/v1/query and also have 2 custom headers.

my current code is

```
$data = array("v" => "20150821", "query" => "whats the time", "lang" => "EN", "sessionId" => "1234567890");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('https://api.api.ai/v1/query');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
//    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    'Content-type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer XxxX-xxx',
    'ocp-apim-subscription-key: XxxX-xxx')
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

If i run this, (with my real auth and key obv) i get nothing. Like Blank. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I AM SO SORRY.
I havent been sleeping well and did a rather idiotic mistake
i forgot to echo $result

i know, i know. I'll have to be a bit more careful
Thanks anyway :P